# Taylor approximation and monotonicity of the function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, taylor-expansion, approximation

Consider a real $f(x)$. If the Taylor approximation of the function is, say, decreasing, can I conclude that the function (near the point were the approximation is made) is decreasing too?

As an example

$$f(x)=\mathrm{lg}(1+\frac{1}{x}) \sim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x}$$
Can I therefore say that,since $\frac{1}{x}$ is decreasing
, then also $f(x)$ is decreasing when $x \to \infty$?

Is there any theorem that links the **Taylor approximation** with the **monotonicity of the function**?

Comment: In your example you are looking at large $x$ but using the Taylor approximation $\ln (1+u) \sim u$ at $0?$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $f(x) = x + 2x^2\sin(1/x),x\ne 0$ with $f(0)=0.$ Then $f'(0) = 1.$ Thus the Taylor polynomial of degree one for $f$ at $0$ is just $x,$ which is increasing. But $f$ is not increasing any any neighborhood of $0.$ To show that, compute $f'(x)$ and verify that $f'(x) < 0$ along a sequence $\to 0.$

A more ambitious example is $f(x) = x+ e^{-1/x^2}\sin(e^{1/x^4}).$ Here $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R),$ $f(0) = 0, f'(0)=1,$ but all higher derivatives of $f$ at $0$ are $0.$ Thus all Taylor polynomials of $f$ at $0$ of degree greater than $0$ are just the polynomial $x.$ But like above, $f'(x) < 0$ along a sequence $\to 0.$

Comment: Thanks for the counterexamples! So this is not true in general but, if I may ask, are there conditions on the function that allow to conclude that the function is increasing/decreasing if the Taylor polynomial is? The functions you proposed are kind of pathological; for more common and simple functions can this be done? I'm asking because Taylor polynomial approximates the function and, for istance, it is positive/negative if the function is positive/negative, so it looks strange that from the polynomial one cannot conclude if the function is increasing or not.